# DataPlotly - displaying percentages over bar graph (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, graph, dataplotly

Is there a way to display percentages above a bar plot? So its easier for viewers to determine how much of an environment is one type (another visual aid). We aren't supposed to show pie graphs. Alternatively, is there a way to display this in the legend(if the other option is not possible)? Otherwise I will go and manually do it for all the graphs. Also is there a way to colour the bar graph in accordance of the feature colour it already has?

Comment: Give a look to this https://gitlab.com/GIS-projects/qgis-geometry-generator-examples/-/tree/master/QML-files%2Fgraph_charts_with_labels

Answer (score 2):

Give a look to [this example](https://gitlab.com/GIS-projects/qgis-geometry-generator-examples/-/tree/master/QML-files%2Fgraph_charts_with_labels) with Geometry Generator created by [Michel Stuyts](https://gitlab.com/mstuyts). 
You can also download a QML file that works with point layers.

[image]

Obviously, you can reuse the code to adapt to your geometry and playing a bit with the expression you can show percentage instead of value.

Answer (score 1):

From DataPlotly 3.5 a new feature has been introduced (https://github.com/ghtmtt/DataPlotly/pull/203).

[image]

You can choose to display as text the additional hover label in the plot advanced configuration. You can also add an expression rather than a pure layer field, so you can use the aggregation functions of QGIS like `"my_field"/sum("my_field")*100` to get the desired result